# Implementing basic semaphore to simple multi-threads program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, semaphore

Please help the Synchronization
       I have to make this program to performe sequentially manner using
       in threads( **ex) thread1 performe and thread2 perforem and so on**)
       But it should be implemented only with Semaphore. I put in the wait(), Signal()
       function to be act like semaphore(but not working)

You just need to see the pthread_join, and thread_work part
  (the main purpose of this program : make 20threads and synchorinize them with semaphore)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define num_thread 20

char str[11];
void *thread_work(void *tid);   //Main body of Thread working
void generate_str(int n);       //Create random character string
void str_sort(void);            //Sorting the generated string into alpabet manner
void check_sort(void);          //Check about "Is the sorting is right"
void print_time(struct timespec *myclock);  //print the time interval of thread work
void print_time_program(struct timespec *myclock);
void wait(void);           //I put in these two function to be act like semaphore
void Signal(void);         //But it does't work
int S=1;

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t tid[num_thread];
  int rc; 
  int t;
  struct timespec myclock[4];
  srand(time(NULL));
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[2]);
  for(t=0; t<num_thread; t++)
      pthread_create(&tid[t], NULL, thread_work, (void *)&t);

  for(t=0; t<num_thread; t++)
      pthread_join(tid[t], NULL);


  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[3]);
  print_time_program(myclock);
  return 0;
}

void *thread_work(void *t)
{
  do
  {
      wait();           //Entry Section

      //CRITICAL SECTION START

              struct timespec myclock[2];
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[0]);   
      int n = *((int *)t);
      printf("########## Thread #%d starting ########## \n", n);
      generate_str(n);
      str_sort();
      check_sort();
      printf("########## Thread #%d exiting  ##########\n", n);
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myclock[1]);
      print_time(myclock);

              //CRITICAL SECTION END

      Signal();
      pthread_exit(NULL);
  }while (1);               

}

void str_sort(void)
{
  int temp;
  int i, j;

  for(i=0; i<9; i++)
      for(j=0; j<9-i; j++)
      {
          if(str[j]>str[j+1])
          {
                  temp=str[j];
              str[j]=str[j+1];
              str[j+1]=temp;
          }
      }
  printf("Sorted string      : %s  ", str);
}

void generate_str(int n)
{
      int i;
  int num;
  srand(n);
  for(i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      num = (97+rand()%26);
      str[i]=num;
  }

  str[10]='\0';
  printf("Initialized string : %s \n", str);
}

void check_sort(void)
{
  int i;
  int count=0;
  for(i=0; i<9; i++)
  {
      if(str[i]>str[i+1])
          count++;
  }
  if(count != 0)
      printf("[X] FALSE \n");
  else
      printf("[O] TRUE \n");
  }

void print_time(struct timespec *myclock)
{
  long delay, temp, temp_n, sec;
  sec = myclock[0].tv_sec % 60;
  printf("Thread Starting Time : %ld.%ld second\n", sec, myclock[0].tv_nsec);
  sec = myclock[1].tv_sec % 60;
  printf("Thread Exiting Time  : %ld.%ld second\n", sec, myclock[1].tv_nsec);

  if (myclock[1].tv_nsec >= myclock[0].tv_nsec) 
  { 
      temp = myclock[1].tv_sec - myclock[0].tv_sec; 
      temp_n = myclock[1].tv_nsec - myclock[0].tv_nsec; 
      delay = 1000000000 * temp + temp_n; 
  }
  else 
  { 
      temp = myclock[1].tv_sec - myclock[0].tv_sec - 1; 
      temp_n = 1000000000 + myclock[1].tv_nsec - myclock[0].tv_nsec; 
      delay = 1000000000 * temp + temp_n; 
  }  

  printf("Thread Working Time  : %ld nano second", delay);
  delay = delay / 1000000;
  printf("(%ld ms)\n\n\n", delay);
  return ;
}

void print_time_program(struct timespec *myclock)
{
  long delay, temp, temp_n, sec;
  sec = myclock[2].tv_sec % 60;
  printf("Program Starting Time : %ld.%ld second\n", sec, myclock[2].tv_nsec);
  sec = myclock[3].tv_sec % 60;
  printf("Program Exiting Time  : %ld.%ld second\n", sec, myclock[3].tv_nsec);

  if (myclock[3].tv_nsec >= myclock[2].tv_nsec) 
  { 
      temp = myclock[3].tv_sec - myclock[2].tv_sec; 
      temp_n = myclock[3].tv_nsec - myclock[2].tv_nsec; 
      delay = 1000000000 * temp + temp_n; 
  }
  else 
  { 
      temp = myclock[3].tv_sec - myclock[2].tv_sec - 1; 
      temp_n = 1000000000 + myclock[3].tv_nsec - myclock[2].tv_nsec; 
      delay = 1000000000 * temp + temp_n; 
  } 

  printf("Program Total Working Time : %ld nano second", delay);
  delay = delay / 1000000;
  printf("(%ld ms)\n\n\n", delay);
  return ;
}

void wait(void)
{
  while( S <= 0);
  S--;
}

void Signal(void)
{
  S++;
}
```

Comment: S needs to be declared as volatile.

Comment: I'd be more likely to read your code if it were properly indented.

Comment: very sorry; It is first time to ask in here....it's hard to put in code;;

Comment: <sigh> - turn threads into really slow sequential code.  Again.

Comment: You can't implement your own semaphores correctly without using stdatomic.h from C11. And even then you can only implement spinning for synchronization and not proper sleeps. So I'd suggest using standard semaphores provided by your pthreads library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how to make threads execute one after another using a semaphore (Linux/Cygwin pthreads):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5

/* global thread exit control flag */
volatile uint32_t g_ExitFlag = 0;

/* global thread execution control semaphore */
sem_t g_Sem;

/* the thread function */
void *ThreadFunc(void *pContext)
{
    uint32_t tid = (uint32_t)pContext;

    /* main thread loop */
    while (g_ExitFlag == 0)
    {
        /* wait for semaphore to be signalled */
        sem_wait(&g_Sem);
        printf("Thread %d running.\n", tid);
    }

    printf("Thread %d exiting.\n", tid);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t i = 0;
    pthread_t th;

    /* suppress warnings */
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    /* initialize the semaphore */
    sem_init(&g_Sem, 0, 0);

    /* create and detach several threads */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&th, NULL, ThreadFunc, (void *)i);
        pthread_detach(th);
    }

    /* run each thread four times and exit */
    for (i = 0; i < (NUM_THREADS * 4); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 15)
        {
            g_ExitFlag = 1;
        }

        /* release a thread to execute */
        sem_post(&g_Sem);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It should be straightforward for you to integrate that kind of functionality into your program.